# How to refresh the access token for using REST API in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

How do I refresh my access token while implementing a Web Activity on Azure?

I have done the following:

1. Created a Web Activtiy to run based on some filters using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP

> ```
>  {
>                 "name": "get pp1 runs based on filters",
>                 "description": "get pp1 runs based on filters.",
>                 "type": "WebActivity",
>                 "dependsOn": [
>                     {
>                         "activity": "Lookup1",
>                         "dependencyConditions": [
>                             "Succeeded"
>                         ]
>                     }
>                 ],
>                 "policy": {
>                     "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
>                     "retry": 0,
>                     "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
>                     "secureOutput": false,
>                     "secureInput": false
>                 },
>                 "userProperties": [],
>                 "typeProperties": {
>                     "url": "POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01",
>                     "method": "POST",
>                     "headers": {
>                         "Content-Type": "application/json",
>                         "Authorization": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize"
>                     },
>                     "body": {
>                         "lastUpdatedAfter": "2023-07-23T12:00:36.33Z",
>                         "lastUpdatedBefore": "2023-07-24T12:01:35Z",
>                         "filters": [
>                             {
>                                 "operand": "pp1",
>                                 "operator": "Equals",
>                                 "values": [
>                                     "pipeline1"
>                                 ]
>                             }
>                         ]
>                     },
>                     "authentication": {
>                         "credential": {
>                             "referenceName": "credential_ref",
>                             "type": "CredentialReference"
>                         },
>                         "type": "UserAssignedManagedIdentity"
>                     }
>                 }
>             },
> ```

I am using **Authentication** as `User Assigned Managed Identity`
and **Integration Runtime** as `AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime`

When I am debugging this, it fails on this webactivtiy and gives me the error: `RefreshMsiAccessToken: accessToken null`

I read a few links and this is because the token expires every 30 mins to 60 mins. How do I continiously ( or in some time interval ) call the access token every one hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you Created a Web Activity to run based on some filters using:  [query-by-factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP) and **Authentication** as `User Assigned Managed Identity`  you need not to provide **Authorization** header in web activity.

**You can follow below steps:**

1. Create a `User Assigned Managed Identity` in your resource group.
   [image]
2. Add your `User Assigned Managed Identity`  in Data Factory managed identity.
   [image]
3. In Data Factory You need to provide **Data Factory Contributor** role to your managed Identity.
   [image]
4. Now in data factory take a web activity and pass the url with authentication as `User Assigned Managed Identity`  and settings as below:
   [image]

**My pipeline.json:**

```json
            {
                "name": "Web1",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "body": {
                        "lastUpdatedAfter": "2023-07-24T00:00:00.3345758Z",
                        "lastUpdatedBefore": "2023-07-26T00:00:00.3686473Z",
                        "filters": [
                            {
                                "operand": "PipelineName",
                                "operator": "Equals",
                                "values": [
                                    "pipeline1"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "authentication": {
                        "resource": "https://management.azure.com/",
                        "credential": {
                            "referenceName": "credential1",
                            "type": "CredentialReference"
                        },
                        "type": "UserAssignedManagedIdentity"
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Output:**

**Pipeline Ran succesfully:**
[image]

Comment: I followed your steps and I get this error. The access is all provided to me.
{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'xx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/querypipelineruns/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xy/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/abc' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}

Comment: provide Data Factory Contributor role to your user managed Identity in data factory.

Comment: Hello, just got that done and refreshed everything and yet it throws the same error. Can it be some other issue? I bascially need a way to refresh my access token because I read it expires within 30-60 mins.

Comment: assign the user Identity to the Contributor role at the subscription level so that the application can fetch the data of data factories in the subscription.

Comment: Hi! I did that and now the status shows as succeed as in your screenshot:) However, I get this in the output: "Operation on target Token failed: {\"error\":\"unauthorized_client\",\"error_description\":\"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier xxxxx)' was not found in the directory 'xyz'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant
This pipeline is a temp pipeline created for this task. Is this an issue or is the status succeeded?