# Why does System Assigned Managed Identity not have access to Azure management API?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-management-api

I was attempting to follow the tutorial here - https://medium.com/azure-tutorials/custom-queue-mechanism-for-data-factory-pipelines-a1b0809ec790

But I can't seem to get the correct authentication. When I try the System Assigned Managed Identity I get error:

```
{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client {client} with object id {object} does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/querypipelineruns/read' over scope '/subscriptions/{subscription}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{datafactory}' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}
```

I have also tried to do a User Assigned Managed Identity by creating it and adding it to the managed identities settings in my data factory, but I get the same error. When I try to call the api in the Microsoft Tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0), everything works fine. Here is my web activity configuration:[image]

Answer (score 0):

> It seems you are making API call to different data factory resource.
> Consider granting `contributor` role for your system assigned managed
> identity on that data factory and retry running web activity to make
> API call.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

User assigned managed identity doesn't have permission to Api that may be the reason for getting above reason. Add **Data factory contributor** role to the user assigned managed identity as follows:

Step 1: Go to the IAM of the blob storage account and click on "Add role assignment" as shown below:

[image]

Step 2: Search for the  `Data factory contributor`  role and select it, as shown below:

Step 3: Select the Managed identity, as shown below:

[image]

Select User-assigned managed identity authentication in web activity as below:

[image]

The pipeline will run successfully without any error:

[image]

Also check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76757606)  SO answer for reference.